# Updating to LineageOS 17.1, replacing su with Magisk

Tags: rooting, updates, twrp, lineageos, magisk

Up to 16.1, LineageOS provided `su` as an add-on, in the shape of an extra zip file which could be installed along with the OS itself using a recovery image such as TWRP.

However, with 17.1 they have discontinued their `su` addon and no longer support root access. Those who still want it are getting pointed to “one of the other `su` solutions out there”.

A quick search pointed me to [Magisk](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/) as pretty much the only solution under active development. However, the install instructions are a bit confusing.

The device is a OnePlus One (bacon), upgrading from LOS 15.1. For now, I am just interested in having a replacement for what `su` offered up to LOS 16.1; any other features offered by Magisk are secondary to me.

Will it work if I just grab the latest Magisk zip from the [Github release page](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/releases) and install it alongside the OS, through the recovery of my choice (currently on TWRP 3.2.2-0)? Or is using Magisk Manager a hard requirement?

Are there any major differences in UX over my current LOS + `su` setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just went through the trouble of solving a similar situation for a OnePlus Nord. Meaning getting root access via Magisk on a LineageOS 17.1 device.

1. "Will it work if I just grab the latest Magisk zip"?

   Yes. I sideloaded it with the LineageOS recovery and after rebooting the system I was able to grant root access to apps using magisk.
2. Are there any major differences in UX over my current LOS + su setup?

   Yes. By installing the magisk zip-file you will get the magisk App which is used for managing your root privileges. I do not have the root option in developer options anymore (as I was used to when using su).

Unfortunately I don't have a bacon here to test your specific case, but maybe my experience will still be helpful.